# Overriding error while creating custom bottom sheet

Tags: android, customization, bottom-sheet

After reading some of the article I started to create my own customBottomSheetBehavior class. I copied the default class from the
[link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.java). I tried to remove all the errors but at the end three same kind of error remained.

`Line 350, 363, & 410` is showing some kind of error. While I looked into some other custom library of this class, I found this `@override` is present, so I believe I should not remove the line but have no idea how to remove that.

Code

```
@Override
  public boolean onStartNestedScroll(
      @NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
      @NonNull V child,
      @NonNull View directTargetChild,
      @NonNull View target,
      int axes,
      int type) {
    lastNestedScrollDy = 0;
    nestedScrolled = false;
    return (axes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedPreScroll(
      @NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
      @NonNull V child,
      @NonNull View target,
      int dx,
      int dy,
      @NonNull int[] consumed,
      int type) {
    if (type == ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH) {
      // Ignore fling here. The ViewDragHelper handles it.
      return;
    }
    View scrollingChild = nestedScrollingChildRef != null ? nestedScrollingChildRef.get() : null;
    if (target != scrollingChild) {
      return;
    }
    int currentTop = child.getTop();
    int newTop = currentTop - dy;
    if (dy > 0) { // Upward
      if (newTop < getExpandedOffset()) {
        consumed[1] = currentTop - getExpandedOffset();
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -consumed[1]);
        setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
      } else {
        consumed[1] = dy;
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -dy);
        setStateInternal(STATE_DRAGGING);
      }
    } else if (dy < 0) { // Downward
      if (!target.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
        if (newTop <= collapsedOffset || hideable) {
          consumed[1] = dy;
          ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -dy);
          setStateInternal(STATE_DRAGGING);
        } else {
          consumed[1] = currentTop - collapsedOffset;
          ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -consumed[1]);
          setStateInternal(STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
      }
    }
    dispatchOnSlide(child.getTop());
    lastNestedScrollDy = dy;
    nestedScrolled = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onStopNestedScroll(
      @NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
      @NonNull V child,
      @NonNull View target,
      int type) {
    if (child.getTop() == getExpandedOffset()) {
      setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
      return;
    }
    if (nestedScrollingChildRef == null
        || target != nestedScrollingChildRef.get()
        || !nestedScrolled) {
      return;
    }
    int top;
    int targetState;
    if (lastNestedScrollDy > 0) {
      top = getExpandedOffset();
      targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
    } else if (hideable && shouldHide(child, getYVelocity())) {
      top = parentHeight;
      targetState = STATE_HIDDEN;
    } else if (lastNestedScrollDy == 0) {
      int currentTop = child.getTop();
      if (fitToContents) {
        if (Math.abs(currentTop - fitToContentsOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
          top = fitToContentsOffset;
          targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        } else {
          top = collapsedOffset;
          targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
      } else {
        if (currentTop < halfExpandedOffset) {
          if (currentTop < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
            top = 0;
            targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
          } else {
            top = halfExpandedOffset;
            targetState = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED;
          }
        } else {
          if (Math.abs(currentTop - halfExpandedOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
            top = halfExpandedOffset;
            targetState = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED;
          } else {
            top = collapsedOffset;
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      top = collapsedOffset;
      targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
    }
    if (viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
      setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
      ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, targetState));
    } else {
      setStateInternal(targetState);
    }
    nestedScrolled = false;
  }
```

Comment: Please attach the part of the code you want help.

Comment: @AndréSousa I have attached the code.

Comment: in all the three method @override is causing the issue